# difference tables 'quote' and 'quote_adress"

Tags: magento2, database, table

What is the '**quote**' table for? And what is the difference between '`quote`' and '`quote_adress`' table ?

Does anyone know what is the difference ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quote in Magento is basically an order that hasn't been placed yet. It contains product items (shopping cart), addresses and payment/shipping methods. It is created as soon as you add an item to cart. During checkout, billing and shipping data is added to the quote. Finally, when the user clicks place order, the quote is converted to an order.

"quote_adress"

A quote object would normally contain 2 address objects, but can contain more if multiple delivery addresses are present.

In regards to the 'collecttotals' method(s): Lets first understand each method, and its purpose:

The method in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote, is the initial entry point for the Totals Collector subsystem, and is initiated by a cart save,

(this allows you to inject class methods into the cart calculations, to affect the outcome of the cart totals - example: calculations of cart discounts)